# Is it necessary to use multi threading concept while updating the same database ?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, database-connection, windows

i have created a windows application(using c# .net) for debugging contest in our department.
in this many user use the same database to select the list of questions and update the marks in their respective id alone.
does it required to use threading concept when they update their marks in the database..
any1 please help me..
thanks in advace...

Answer (score 3):

`Mutil-Threading` or multiple threads are used in scenarios where you want to do more than one task at one time or do some tasks simultaneously. You should think about your scenario and possible use of multiple threads in your scenario. If you think there is some task which can be divided in to two separate tasks and they can run in parallel, you can use multi-threading to gain performance improvements. Similarly if you think there is some task that is heavy and takes huge time you can move that task to `Background Thread` and use main thread to deal with some other task in parallel. It all depends on your scenario.

Now coming to your scenario if it is a windows forms application most likely there will be only one user of this app at one time who will be interacting through UI. If this assumption is correct i don't think so you will need multi-threading. If user is doing some inputs thorough UI and he clicks save button at the end to save info in DB you don't need multi-threading a single UI thread will be enough to do this

Answer (score 0):

No this is not needed. Each user will cosume a connection from the database **connection pool**, and those work concurrently and no parallel programming is required.

Answer (score 0):

If you update a database from different threads, it will not corrupt. This is different from regular C#, where you need to apply locks to protect your objects. You may be required to use transactions to ensure that your database updates don't interfere with each other at a higher level. Very simply put, transactions ensure that your database stays consistent if you edit your database at multiple tables, or if your database changes depend on the database contents, such as adding an order from a customer, transactions prevent you add an order for a deleted customer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use non-UI thread for any database interactions, otherwise UI may become unresponsive. E.g. if you execute a long query from UI thread (or your connection was disrupted, or the database is under heavy use or whatever, anything that can go wrong - will go wrong), UI thread gets blocked until full response is received.

In the situations where you have multiple users, which may update the same data in the database, you may need to introduce transactions to ensure correct control and data flow - ACID.